# Passing data frame fields to a regression model in a function

Tags: r, function, lm

I am just a few months into using R and this is my first post. I am looking to create a function that takes fields from a data frame, filters the outliers via quantiles, then writes the regression parameters as annotations on a scatter plot. The filtering and plotting work correctly but I get an error in the linear model. Can I convert those fields to execute in the model?

Error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = df[, field1] ~ df[, field2], drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
> invalid type (list) for variable 'df[, field1]'

Here is the function:

```
scatter_filtered <- function(df,field1,field2,field3) {

  range1 <- quantile(df[, field1], probs= c(0.1,0.9), na.rm=TRUE)
  range2 <- quantile(df[, field2], probs= c(0.1,0.9), na.rm=TRUE)

    low_end1 <- range1[1]
    high_end1 <- range1[2]
    low_end2 <- range2[1]
    high_end2 <- range2[2]

  df %>%
filter(df[, field1] > low_end1, df[, field1] < high_end1,
           df[, field2] > low_end2, df[, field2] < high_end2) %>%
    model <- lm(df[,field1] ~ df[, field2])
      r_output <- round(glance(model)$r.squared, digits = 5)
      r_adj_output <- round(glance(model)$adj.r.squared, digits = 5)
      p_output <- round(glance(model)$p.value, digits = 5) %>%
  ggplot(aes_string(x = field1, y = field2, color = field3)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) 
    #  annotate("text", label = paste("r_sq:",r_output), x=0.1, y=0.1, parse=TRUE) +
    #  annotate("text", label = paste("p-val:",p_output), x=0.1, y=0.1, parse=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: After the second line there is `%>%` before the `model <-`

Comment: Take a look at this instruction: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Thanks, a very helpful post on dplyr.